# python utcfromtimestamp for -144714 returns error

Tags: django, python-3.6

I have faced a bad error. I am using django and I am saving my `datetime` values as epoch time in database but when I want to convert them in python I face an error.

if I use this code

```
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(-14471).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'1969-12-31'
```

it works fine but if I use

```
    datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(-144714).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

it does not work. well I can not convert my database values but why this error happens. what other options do I have to deal with this problem and why it shows such behavior ?

I am using python 3.6.4

I also tried this one and it give me the same error

```
utc_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(-698577777, timezone.utc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
utc_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(12525, timezone.utc)
works..
```

Here is another test

```
    Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> utc_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(-698577777, datetime.timezone.utc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>>> datetime.datetime(1947, 11, 12, 14, 37, 3, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(1947, 11, 12, 14, 37, 3, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> datetime.MINYEAR
1
>>> datetime.MAXYEAR
9999
>>>
```

Comment: Which range of years do you need to store?

Comment: @dahrens I want to store different ranges it might be from 1800 up to now

Comment: And which DBMS are you using? I would consider using another format than unix timestamps to store the data in the databases.

Comment: @dahrens I am using postsql, What other formats are possible?

Comment: [date/time fields in postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html). Usually, when django handles this through the models, there should not be an issue. Do you use [Datefield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield)?

Comment: @dahrens In fact I am using django models now, but I want to convert those date time values to other formats (jalali,persian date) and most of related algorithms take epoch timestamp, I can convert date time to epoch but when I get Jalali date as unix time I can not convert them into python date and time due to this problem

Comment: I've added some information in my anser (for readability). Which operating system are you using? The datetime functions are using an underlying C implementation which differs between environments. Can you please repeat the same for your environment?

Comment: @dahrens Hi thanks for your help, I am on windows, is the problem because of windows?

Comment: @dahrens I added the results of your provided scripts, again it raises the same error

Comment: I'll give this a try on my windows vbox at work tomorrow. Which libary do you use for jalali? [jdatetime](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jdatetime/) can convert datetime objects directly. I tried it from within python3. `jdatetime.date.fromgregorian(day=20,month=2,year=2018)` - this way you might work with datetime object directly.

Comment: @dahrens thanks very much, I am converting data to jalali in javascript side. I want to send and receive data using unix format. I am using https://github.com/beygi/bootstrap-persian-datetimepicker

Comment: I received the same error on my windows box. Looks like the underlying C library behaves different in this case. As already written in the official documentation they often only accept dates between 1970 and 2038. I would start digging through the JS library and try to use another format then unix timestamp to circumvent this issue.

Comment: @dahrens thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp):

> This may raise OverflowError, if the timestamp is out of the range of values supported by the platform C gmtime() function, and OSError on gmtime() failure. It’s common for this to be restricted to years in 1970 through 2038

The docs also tell you how to work around this issue:

> To get an aware datetime object, call fromtimestamp():

`datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, timezone.utc)`

> On the POSIX compliant platforms, it is equivalent to the following expression:

`datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc) + timedelta(seconds=timestamp)`

> except the latter formula always supports the full years range: between `MINYEAR` and `MAXYEAR` inclusive.

Regaring your addition in the question. On ubuntu linux 16.04 LTS your code runs fine in a python 3.5.2 shell:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> utc_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(-698577777, datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> utc_time
datetime.datetime(1947, 11, 12, 14, 37, 3, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> datetime.MINYEAR
1
>>> datetime.MAXYEAR
9999
```

Comment: thanks datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, timezone.utc) gets timestamp as int ? and what about timezone?

Comment: I again tested with another method (the question is updated) and it gives me the same error which is again about using a nagetive value

Comment: What are the values of MINYEAR and MAXYEAR in your environment?

Comment: I used datetime.min and it returned datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)